# JSch port forwarding on docker

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, jsch, pg-dump

I have created a java application that need to connecto to a PostgreSQL database do run a backup (via pg_dump). As the only way to connect on the database is using a SSH tunnel, I created a routine that stablishes the connection and that run the pg_dump using java Process executor.

The code runs very well directly on Windows and Linux (Ubuntu), but when I try to run it in a docker container, pg_dump cannot use/find the forwarded port.

This is the java code:

```java
final JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session = jsch.getSession("user", "xxx.com", 22);

jsch.addIdentity("my-private-key.pem");

session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig("ConnectionAttempts", "3");

session.connect();

session.setPortForwardingL(5440, "xxx.postgres.server.xxx", 5432);
```

And this is the Dockerfile

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11-openj9:jre-11.0.8_10_openj9-0.21.0-alpine

WORKDIR /opt/app

COPY target/app*.jar /opt/app/app.jar

RUN apk add bash postgresql-client

ENTRYPOINT exec java -Djava.security.egd=fiile:/dev/./urandom $JAVA_OPTS -jar app.jar
```

And that is the error returned when executing the pg_dump

```
executing command /usr/bin/pg_dump -p 5441 -d ...
pg_dump: error: connection to database "erpx" failed: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
       Is the server running locally and accepting
       connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5441"?
ended with exit code 1
```

I tried to create a break-point and debbug de application remotely to check if the port is available, but it seems to not open the port, so I suspect that it could be some security setting on docker. I already tried to run the container using --privileged=true, --network=host, exposing the port 5441 and usign a hight port number (ex. 50321), but nothing worked. I also tried using alpine and ubuntu docker images and openjdk and openj9 java 11, but the result was the same.

Comment: Where is the database running? Can you verify that the docker container has connectivity to the database, i.e. that you can ping the database server from the pod?

Comment: The database runs on AWS (RDS). I can't connect dirrectly, so I use a bastion machine as ssh tunnel and forward the connection to the RDS through the bastion. I can ping the bastion dirrectly, but not the RDS.

Comment: Can you ping the bastion? Can you ping google? I suspect that there is something wrong with the virtual network setup.

Comment: Yes, I can ping both

Comment: From the container, yes?

Comment: yes, from inside the container

Comment: Actually it was my fault... as I am connecting locally I was not passign the -h parameter, as normally it assumes localhost as the default host it this case. Just passing the paramerer solved the problem.